# Accessing .net function from jquery popup is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, popup

In my asp.net application, I am trying to send-back values from my popup windows to a function written in .cs file. I have written following code for pop-up window:

```
function SaveFileHistory() {
    debugger;
    var file = {};
    file.FileStatus = $('#MainContent_txtFirstName').val();
    file.AssignedTo = $('#MainContent_txtLastName').val();
    file.Notes = $('#MainContent_txtNotes').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'FileCreationForm.aspx/SaveFileHistory',
        method: 'post',
        data: '{ FileHistoryBO:' + JSON.stringify(file) + '}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {
            //loadEmployees();
            dialogDiv.dialog('close');
            clearInputFields();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

When I am debugging through chrome I can see the values are retrieving successfully. But the function in .cs file is not calling, I mean the line in jquery function - `"url: FileCreationForm.aspx/SaveFileHistory"` is not working. So the function `SaveFileHistory()` in `FileCreationForm.aspx` file is not being called.

Any clue?

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console

Comment: You method needs to be a static method and need to have [WebMethod] attribute.

Comment: Share your cs code if this doesn't help.

Comment: I am trying to send values individually like - data: "{'FileStatus':'" + FileStatus + "','AssignedTo':'" + AssignedTo + "','Notes':'" + Notes + "'}", But getting error : FileStatus is not defined. ReferenceError: FileStatus is not defined↵    at eval (eval at success (http://localhost:8773/Transaction/FileCreationForm?id=1:37:25), <anonymous>:1:1)↵    at Object.success (http://localhost:8773/Transaction/FileCreationForm?id=1

Comment: can you post the signature of your SaveFileHistory method from cs file.

Comment: [WebMethod]
        public void SaveFileHistory(string FileStatus, string AssignedTo, string Notes)
        {
            FileHistoryBO file = new FileHistoryBO();

            file.Id = 0;
            file.FileId = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            file.FileStatus = 1;
            file.AssignedTo = Convert.ToInt32(AssignedTo);
            file.Notes = Notes;
        }. This method is giving 505 error. But if I make the function static then I can access the function. But I don't want to use static function as there are some limitations. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` attribute on your function in aspx.cs file

Comment: I am trying to send values individually like - data: "{'FileStatus':'" + FileStatus + "','AssignedTo':'" + AssignedTo + "','Notes':'" + Notes + "'}", But getting error : FileStatus is not defined. ReferenceError: FileStatus is not defined↵ at eval (eval at success (localhost:8773/Transaction/FileCreationForm?id=1:37:25), <anonymous>:1:1)↵ at Object.success (localhost:8773/Transaction/FileCreationForm?id=1